# How to update all values in an Excel file?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to write a macro that updates all values in an Excel file to new ones?
For example I have

in A1 cell:
`='C:\[file1.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1` with a value 40

in A2 cell:
`='C:\[file2.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1` with a value 50

But these files have now new values in these cells: 41 and 51.

I know how to write it manually, when I know the name of files.

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="C:\file1.xls", Type:= _
        xlExcelLinks
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="C:\file2.xls", Type:= _
        xlExcelLinks
```

but is possible to update all values if I don't know the names of all files?
Something like

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateAllLinks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found in the VBA help:

```
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ThisWorkbook.LinkSources
```

Just enter ***UpdateLink*** into the VBE, select the word and press F1 to see the VBA-Help.